# Logical Connectives and Quantifiers

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

So I have been told that the rule of thumb when symbolizing Existence statements is to use the "and/$\wedge$" logical connective.

$$\exists x (P_x \wedge Q_x)$$

Whereas symbolizing a Universal statement usually uses a "conditional/$\rightarrow$".

$$\forall x(P_x\to Q_x)$$

But when we compound the quantifiers, should we base the main logical connector on the innermost or the outermost quantifier?

$$\forall x \exists y(P_x\wedge Q_y)\text{ or }\forall x \exists y (P_x\to Q_y)$$

If there is no general rule, what is the reasoning behind choosing the correct logical connective for compound statements?

Comment: Whoever told you that is misleading you. Those are the way they tend to appear most frequently based on what the statement is trying to say, but there are plenty of times, for instance, when you will want $\forall x(P_x \land Q_x)$. There is no "correct" form. It depends on what the statement is meant to express. Either version of your proposals can be correct depending on the context.

Comment: It may be helpful to deep the "rule of thumb" in mind, but not strictly so, @Isaac.

Comment: The prime rule of thumb: The rule of thumb doesn't apply here.

Comment: In mathematical proofs using set theory, $\forall x\in S: P(x)$ is translated $\forall x:[x\in S \implies P(x)].$ And $\exists x\in S: P(x)$ is translated $\exists x:[x \in S \land P(x)].$ Unless you are intentionally trying to confuse readers (can be fun, see Drinkers' Paradox), you should avoid constructs of the form $\exists x: [x\in S \implies P(x)]$. It can be shown that for any set $S$ and unary predicate $P$, this statement will always be true (assuming non-existence of a universal set).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What he is likely referring to is sometimes you will have relations appear informally inside the quantifier, and those are the rules for how it is translated. For instance,

$(\forall x \in I)P(x)$ informally expresses $(\forall x)(x\in I \to P(x))$

and $(\exists x \in I)P(x)$ informally expresses $(\exists x)(x \in I \land P(x))$

EDIT-

In response to your comment, if he/she is referring to the informal notation above the correct way would be something like the following:

$(\forall x \in I)(\exists y >0)(P(x,y))$ would be translated

$(\forall x)\Big((x \in I) \to \exists y\big((y > 0) \land P(x,y)\big)\Big)$

So you use both. Absent this, I don't know which convention he could be referring to because both can be correct depending on what the statement itself is trying to express. There are plenty of times when you want weaker statements. For instance, you generally want the weakest possible assumptions that suffice to prove a given theorem. This allows you to use the theorem more broadly/frequently as the conditions that must be met to employ it are easier to satisfy.

Comment: The explanation given was that $\exists x (P_x\to Q_x)$ is usually too weak to be useful. Primarily because $\exists x (P_x\to Q_x)$::$\exists x (\neg P_x\vee Q_x)$. I should have been more clear that this doesn't violate any logical rules. Rather, I was asking which could be the correct convention for compound statements.

Answer (score 2):

There are no rules of thumb when it comes down to expressing logical statements - depending on what you want to express you may need to use one connective or another.

For example, suppose you want to express that for every number $n$ which is not prime there is another number $m$ different from $n$ and $1$ such that $m$ divides $n$.

Then you may express this as $\forall n \exists m . \neg isPrime(n) \implies Divides(m,n) \wedge m\neq n $

Comment: Better yet, your translation should  be $$\forall n\Big ( \lnot \text{isPrime}(n) \to \exists m\big(\text{Divides}(m, n) \land (m\neq n) \land (m \neq 1)\big)\Big)$$

Comment: And indeed, the outer quantifier shapes the style we typically use when we are speaking about all n, while the inner quantifier shapes the style we typically use when we are speaking about one or some m.